# Dual SIM device : How to configure data usage on per app basis (Rooted device)

Tags: mobile-data, automation, dual-sim, macrodroid

My Moto X Play (6.0.1, rooted, Xposed installed ) has dual SIM options, which I usually don't use. Recently, I had a need to use two SIMs, borrowed one with generous data allowance and second (personal ) SIM which was halfway to hitting the data cap.

My need was to configure data usage on a per app basis so that :

- I don't exhaust data on my personal SIM while being able to use mobile number linked accounts like WhatsApp, Uber, banking accounts etc.
- For all other apps , use the data from borrowed SIM

I couldn't find an app  to do this, as is evident from this similar question, which has no responses yet -[Is there a way on a DUAL SIM Android phone to configure on a per-app basis, which app uses which sim card to access internet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/173937/131553)

**How do I configure SIM data usage on per app basis ?**

(This is a self answered question to share one way of doing it. You are welcome to post alternate solutions )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requires Rooted Device, [Xposed framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) installed,  latest version of [GravityBox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.marshmallow.gravitybox) Xposed module and an [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app - I use [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)

Create a macro in Macrodroid

**Trigger:**

- Application Launched → select from the drop down list, all apps you want to use on SIM card linked to banking, WhatsApp, Uber etc (5 apps in example below )
- Application Launched → select from the drop down list, all apps you want to use on *second* SIM card (16 apps in example below )

( Make sure that apps *don't* appear on both lists !)

**Actions:**

- If → **`+`**  → Trigger Fired  →
  Application Launched 5 apps 
  →
- Tap End If and add this action - Launch Shortcut  → GravityBox actions  → SIM settings  →  SIM 1 for data

Repeat this for second set of apps and choose SIM 2 for data

**Constraints:**   Leave blank

Done !

[image]