# Screenshots: captured by front camera or back camera?

Tags: screenshots

I see that screenshots posted in my answers seem to be grainy. [Example](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180065/131553)

Thinking of it made me wonder which camera is used - front or back and is there a way / hack / app to improve the quality of screenshot ?

Changing brightness helps a little but *grainy* texture remains

Device : Moto X Play, Stock, Rooted , Xposed installed

Comment: This is interesting, can you provide an example here?

Comment: @NicolaGalluccio: updated with example to show most recent one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Remove that lowercase "m" in https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX*m*.png ([More Info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298822/350567))

The screenshot has **nothing to do with your cameras**. A screenshot is taken by the system (or the graphics driver), who takes one frame from its rendering buffer and saves the frame. Thus a screenshot always has the same resolution as your screen, and is always a PNG.

Changing brightness should have no effect on your screenshots taken, because it does nothing to the images rendered by your graphics processor. For LCD screens, brightness is simply the power supplied to the backlight panel, and the masking (front) panel is not affected. To confirm this, find a static screen and take two shots with different brightness levels. Compare those screenshots pixel-by-pixel and you'll find them *exactly the same*.

For grainy textures, it's Imgur's service for resizing photos that caused that problem.

I've edited your example post and here's the change:

```
[![enter image description here][1m]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L21J7.png
  [1m]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L21J7m.png
```

See for yourself