# Automatically disable SIM 2 while SIM 1 has signal?

Tags: tasker, sim-card, automation, dual-sim

Is it possible (via Tasker or otherwise) to automatically disable a SIM when the other one has a signal, and to similarly re-enable it once the other loses signal?

Comment: For sure you would require root. Related https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180064/131553

Comment: Yeah root is fine, I have root. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.