# Disable/enable second DualSIM card command

Tags: tasker, automation, sim-card, macrodroid

I use the MarcoDroid app to change phone settings depending on events.

I want to turn on and off the second sim card depending on the event. I found a command option where I can type the command to enable/disable the second SIM card. I just don't know what the command will be for the Moto Z2 Play phone?

The settings are shown in the print screen. Can anyone tell me how to search for a command and its parameters?

EDIT:

I found a command that you can use to change whether the phone is to be multisim or singlesim.

For dual sim:

```
su -c setprop persist.radio.multisim.config dsds
```

For single sim:

```
su -c setprop persist.radio.multisim.config none
```

The problem is that when I run the command to turn off the second sim card from the console, in the settings there is no option to choose which sim card should be responsible for what, but the card itself remains turned on. Incoming calls do not show up, but the caller has a call tone.

Maybe someone has an idea what other parameter in the console is responsible for turning off the second sim card?

[image: MacroDroid settings]

Comment: [This service call needs device to be rooted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739201). If your device is rooted and has gravity box installed, you can use gravitybox shortcuts to disable SIM using MacroDroid. As in this [somewhat related answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180065/131553) instead of trying to figure out device /OS/ version specific code as the first link says, unless you have other reasons

Comment: I installed root, but GravityBox hasn't option to disable the second sim card. But I found command to change state SIM card, but it works halfway. I described it in the post.